# Rails: create symlink with capistrano before initializer from config/initializers is executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, symlink

I have a capistrano task that is executed like this in deploy.rb:

```
after  'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:create_symlink'
```

The task:

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance.load do
    namespace :deploy do
         task :create_symlink do
           run "touch #{shared_path}/somefile.yml"
           run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/somefile.yml #{release_path}/config/somefile.yml"
         end
    end
end
```

configs are loaded from somefile.yml like this:

```
customconf = OpenStruct.new(YAML::load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'somefile.yml'))[Rails.env]||{})
```

The issue that I'm having is that the configs are loaded in config/initializers/customconfig.rb. but the symlink seems to be created after the code in customconfig.rb is created.

This is the error I'm getting when trying to cap deploy:

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /var/www/vhosts/mysite/rails/releases/20170705083649/config/somefile.yml

Basically how can I load the configs from somefile.yml after the symlink is created. Or how can I run the cap task before the initializer is executed?

Comment: just put these config in shared folder which is created by the capitrano

Comment: The somefile.yml? I already did that. The symlink is also created properly. But it is created after I try to access it in the initializer it seems.

Comment: Directory are not same for both the condition. I think you should check it over .a symlink is created in right path or not .... bcoz i can see the path of release -> config

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say here, but the symlink is created correctly to the correct path. See my own answer to this question below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by changing `after  'deploy:update_code'` to after `after 'deploy:finalize_update'`. But I want to ask if this is the correct way of doing it before I accept this as accepted answer.